# override design_config_form.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, uicomponent

How can I override `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` in `Magento 2.1.2`?

Basically, I want to fix favicon issue, as described [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5478) in my custom module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply copy that file after fixing it in your module folder under `view/adminhtml/ui_component/`